# Importing CSV file - mysql datatype for date

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, mysqlimport

I'm having an issue with importing some data that contains a date / time field which looks like:

Wed Apr 08 15:11:50 UTC 2015

When I import this I get "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

Is there something I can do to import this field into a datatype of datetime?  Do I need to do some sort of convert process so the data will be in the correct format?

Thanks in advance.
Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Wed Apr 08 15:11:50 UTC 2015', '%a %M %d %H:%i:%s UTC %Y');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Wed Apr 08 15:11:50 UTC 2015', '%a %M %d %H:%i:%s UTC %Y') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-04-08 15:11:50                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Depending on how you are importing, you may need to first put it into an `@variable`, the convert using `real_col_name = STR_TO_DATE(@variable, '%a...')`